# R how to store jagged arrays

Tags: arrays, r

Here, I need to build a jagged arrays to store data, here is the code for you

```
a<-list()  
b=1 
for(i in 1:5){
 b+1
 a[i]<-array(0,c(b,1))
}
```

You can see, what I want to do it to save arrays of different dimensions, even though here is 0 as an example, into a.

Would you please help me on how to create a jagged arrays/lists/matrices, to store different dimensions arrays?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean `b <- b+1`? `b+1` does not do anything in your code.  Also, you index into lists using `[[` rather  than `[`.  If that doesn't answer your questions, please explain what your desired output is supposed to be...

Comment: @Justin, I got it, I need to use [[ , instead of [. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

For create jagged arrays also know as ragged arrays this is an example using list function and using x[1] for indexing:

```
x = list(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(-1,-3,-4),c=c(23,45,23,45,25,48),d=c(2,1))
stk = stack(x)
ustk= unstack(stk)
identical(ustk,x)
[1] TRUE
> x
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$b
[1] -1 -3 -4

$c
[1] 23 45 23 45 24 48

$d
[1] 2 1

> x[1]
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

> x[2]
$b
[1] -1 -3 -4
```

other method:

```
# empty list to start with
X <- list()
# we get a vector
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# add it to the ragged array
X <- c(X, list(v1))
# get another couple of vectors and add them as well
v2 <- c(9, 8, 7, 6)
v3 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
X <- c(X, list(v2, v3))

# add some more elements to the first vector in 
# the vector directly
X[[1]] <- c(X[[1]], 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

For created jagged matrices this is an example:

```
x = c(3,2,5)
struct = lapply(x, function(i){ 
    sapply(1:i, function(k){
        c(rep(NA, k-1),exp( - (0:(i-k))))
    })
})
> x
[1] 3 2 5
> struct
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000        NA   NA
[2,] 0.3678794 1.0000000   NA
[3,] 0.1353353 0.3678794    1

[[2]]
          [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000   NA
[2,] 0.3678794    1

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.00000000         NA        NA        NA   NA
[2,] 0.36787944 1.00000000        NA        NA   NA
[3,] 0.13533528 0.36787944 1.0000000        NA   NA
[4,] 0.04978707 0.13533528 0.3678794 1.0000000   NA
[5,] 0.01831564 0.04978707 0.1353353 0.3678794    1
```